# Converting small letters to capitals

Tags: haskell

I'm stuck on a question in the book, 'Haskell - The Craft of Functional Programming'. Ex 3.16:

> Define a function to convert small letters to capitals which returns unchanged characters which are not small letters.

Is there something I'm missing? If I convert small letters to capitals how can I return a character that is unchanged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there's a bit missing:

> Define a function to convert small letters to capitals **and** which returns unchanged characters **for those** which are not small letters

For example:

```
toCapital 'c' == 'C' -- lower case c to upper case C
toCapital 'o' == 'O' -- lower case o to upper case O
toCapital 'C' == 'C' -- upper case C gets returned without change
toCapital '3' == '3' -- numbers get returned without change
toCapital '_' == '_' -- other things also get returned without change
```

Comment: @Zeta: well that spoils the exercise :-)

Comment: Well, that's only 5 patterns of at least 26 ones :D (unless we include non-ASCII characters). But seriously, at least two examples (like `toCapital '3'` and `toCapital 'c'`) would help any reader. It's strange that they didn't get included.

Comment: There's nothing missing in the quoted text: it's perhaps not as clear as it could be, but it is a perfectly fine sentence that means the same thing as your corrected version. Try parsing it instead like this: Define a function to convert small letters to capitals, which returns (unchanged) characters which are not small letters. The extra punctuation should make it more clear, but again is not necessary.